# How can I recolor the very first candle on tradingview.com using pine script if it breaches a particular price?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to color the first candle to a different color in a 15 minute chart based on certain conditions. Is this possible?

I am using the below code to color the first candle in either yellow or purple if it meets some conditions but it seems to color all the subsequent candles as well.

```
study(title="OR", shorttitle="OpeningRange", overlay=true)
up15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range High")
down15on = input(true, title="15 Minute Opening Range Low")
is_newbar(res) => change(time(res)) != 0 
adopt(r, s) => security(syminfo.tickerid, r, s) 
high_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),high,0)
low_range = valuewhen(is_newbar('D'),low,0)
candle_color = close>adopt('15', high_range) ? color.purple :
 close<adopt('15', low_range) ? color.yellow :
 na
barcolor( candle_color )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by first candle you actually mean the last one and not the candle where `bar_index = 0`

In which case you can make use of `show_last` in `barcolor` as follows:

`barcolor(candle_color,show_last=1)`

This will only color the last candle on the chart. If you actually mean the first candle so `bar_index=0` then use:

`barcolor(barstate.isfirst ? candle_color : na)`